# Is it Multiple Regression that I should chose?

Tags: regression, time-series

I am trying to assess how the degree of CSR activity could change the financial results of a company. For this, my independent variable would be a CSR score (fluctuations of which give me the variations) & my dependent variables would be a few financial indicators.

My issues are:

1. Can I use multiple regression for this?
2. How can I evaluate this for a period of say 10 years?
3. Am I able to bring all dependent variables & make a score & make this a linear regression model?
4. But then again I want to bring some control variables such as size of the company & risk levels etc.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: CSR = Corporate Social Responsibility? Your (3) doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please help...I think I replied & posted the reply wrongly! I am desperate for a response...Many Thanks

Comment: I suspect people (including myself) may be reluctant to jump in because this is a broad question that needs complex, specialized treatment, as @Michael's reply suggests.  Certainly "multiple regression" in some form will be involved in the analysis.  However--I mean no offense, I'm trying to help--anyone who has to ask that is not going to be up to the task of conducting the analysis itself.  You need to seek out the services of an expert who can spend some time learning about your objectives and assessing the nature and availability of data.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a question of causal inference and those questions are tough to answer when you can't design a randomized controlled experiment.  That said, regression or time-series analysis may tell you some things you're interested to know about the association between between variables such as CSR activity and profitability.

If you have a more specific hypothesis about how CSR activity will influence profitability, e.g. a two year lag between CSR activity and its effects on profitability then you can customize your analysis to focus on such hypotheses.

Ask yourself, do you expect individual companies' profitability to vary depending on their previous CSR activity?  Do you expect companies profitability to differ from each other based on their previous CSR activity?  Both?

What kind of data do you have access to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael.
Yes, my aim is to identify fluctuations in CSR rating (from FTSE index) over years for some companies & see how thier profitability has varied over those years. Asuuming that other things remained constant, my argument would be that the changes in the profitability would be due to the varying levels of CSR activity.
I do not wish to do an analysis among companies. My analysis will only be over years of some companies.
Does this make sense? Please respond.
Many Thanks